# Orders of Magnitude: Practially How big is infinite in Stat. Mech. Thermodynamic Limit?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

[In this MIT OCW lecture notes doc](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-334-statistical-mechanics-ii-statistical-physics-of-fields-spring-2014/lecture-notes/MIT8_334S14_Lec2.pdf)
"The  canonical  partition  function  for  a  finite  collection  of  particles  is  always  an 
analytical  function.  Hence  phase  transitions,  and  their  associated  non–analyticities,  are 
only  obtained  for  infinitely  many  particles,  i.e.  in  the 
thermodynamic limit, $N \rightarrow \infty$
. The 
study  of  phase  transitions  is  thus  related  to  finding  the  origin  of  various  singularities  in 
the  free  energy  and  characterizing  them."

**But there aren't infinite particles!**

- Is this another time where I should interpret infinity as *very large compared to the system size*?
- How many particles should we practically consider infinite? A mole?

Comment: Depends on the system in question, and the particular nature of the interactions in question. For an extreme example, quark-gluon plasma, which is very strongly interacting, behaves in a way that can be described by hydrodynamics when the system has as few as 1000 particles in it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. What sort of system would be an extreme case on the high end of the spectrum?

Comment: A very cold solid, maybe. The minimum energy of the excitations in the solid is related to the size of the cube. In an infinite lattice, you can have excitations of any energy, but as soon as you have a finite lattice of any size, you have imposed a cutoff on your phonon energy spectrum. Regardless of system size, there's always a cold enough temperature that this cutoff is important.

Comment: I tried googling "Cold solid thermodynamic limit" and I'm not seeing anything directly related. Could you point me to a book, paper, video or keywords that would point me to what you are talking about?

Comment: The keyword here is "finite-size effects" or occasionally just "size effects." Here's a paper that covers some of the ways they impact heat conduction: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5105.pdf. I point your attention to the following passage: "Significant heat may be carried by phonons with wavelengths of... thousands in units of $a$," where $a$ is the atomic spacing. The lower temperature your solid is, the more of these longer-wavelength phonons there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it depends. It depends on the specifical problem you are considering and it depends on the temperature and the other parameters.

In general, in equilibrium statistical mechanics, one is dealing with integrals of the type
$$
\langle O \rangle = \frac{1}{Z} \int dx \ O(x) \exp( - N F(x) ) \ ,
$$
where
$$
Z = \int dx \exp( - N F(x) ) \ .
$$

If $N \to \infty$, one can use Laplace's method (or the saddle point method) to get
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\langle O \rangle = O(x^\ast)
$$
where $F(x^\ast) = \min_{x} F(x)$.

The question can be rephrased in ``how important the neglected term are?''. Applying the Laplace's method (or saddle point in case of complex variables) to the first two equation we obtain
$$
Z = \int dx \exp( - N F(x) ) \approx \int dx \exp( - N F(x^\ast) - \frac{N}{2} F''(x^\ast)(x-x^\ast)^2 )  \ ,
$$
and therefore
$$
\langle O \rangle \approx \frac{ \int dx \ O(x) \exp( - N F(x^\ast) - \frac{N}{2} F''(x^\ast)(x-x^\ast)^2 ) }{
\int dx \ \exp( - N F(x^\ast) - \frac{N}{2} F''(x^\ast)(x-x^\ast)^2 ) 
} = \\ = \sqrt{\frac{N F''(x^\ast)}{2 \pi}} \int dx \ O(x) \exp( - \frac{N}{2} F''(x^\ast)(x-x^\ast)^2 )  \ .
$$
This last integral is the average over a Gaussian with mean $x^\ast$ and variance $1/(N F''(x^\ast))$. In the limit of $N \to \infty$, one gets $O(x^\ast)$. One the other hand, one can get the fluctuations around this limit. Using $y = x - x^\ast$ and expanding around $y = 0$
$$
\langle O \rangle \approx \sqrt{\frac{N F''(x^\ast)}{2 \pi}} \int dx \ \left( O(x^\ast) + O'(x^\ast) y + O''(x^\ast) \frac{y^2}{2} + ... \right) \exp( - \frac{N}{2} F''(x^\ast) y^2 ) = \\
= O(x^\ast) + \frac{1}{N} \frac{O''(x^\ast)}{F''(x^\ast)} + ... \ .
$$

Therefore the error is of order $1/N$. How important this term is depends on $O(x^\ast)$, $O''(x^\ast)$ and $F''(x^\ast)$.